# Pull the dropdown value into Elementor Column

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I apply this to elementor column ?

I want the output to displayed in a column in Elementor from a dropdown . I already assigned an Class ID for the column .

I use this :

```
    var StateAdd = $("#input_15_3").val();
    $( "#fenceStateDisplay option[value="+StateAdd+"]"" ).text(StateAdd);
```

But the value doesn't appear .

Can someone please help me with my code .

Thanks in advance .

Edit :
I am using wordpress and Elementor Builder Plugin .

#input_15_3 is the dropdown ID for State . I want it to be displayed in the comlumn made by Elementor which I assigned with css ID #fenceStateDisplay .

How can I correct my code ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi coatedpiLL. First, please make sure your code is using the code formatting. To activate it, make sure there is a blank line above your code (below "I use this:"). Also, there is an extra double quote (`"`) near the end of your code. Finally can you share the HTML that your are trying to change? Also, are there any JavaScript errors in the console?  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65924976/edit) to add this to make it better.

Comment: Thanks. i already edited my question .

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the `<option>` tag you are trying to select? Also what is the value of `StateAdd` you are trying to find. Finally, you still have an extra double quote (`"`) in your code on your last line (`"]""` => `"]"`).

Comment: @ThomasF I took a screenshot . Please see attached image . I used Gravity forms plugin to create the form . Please click this --> [link](https://imgur.com/9E89ayZ)

Comment: @ThomasF Here is my new code


`var StateAdd = $("#input_15_3").val();<br/>
$( "#fenceStateDisplay option[value="+StateAdd+"]" ).text();`

Comment: @ThomasF I came up with a new code but it is still not working  <br />

`$("select#input_15_3").change(function(){
var yourstate = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
$("#fenceStateDisplay").val(yourstate);
});`
<br />
Please see attached image <br />
[dropdown1](https://imgur.com/owgFz2O)
[dropdown2](https://imgur.com/85FdoVt)